# constexpr compiler error - is not usable in a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++20

Can we not "normalize" the behavior of a constexpr function by using is_constant_evaluated ? I understand why the successful cases work, but can't wrap my head around why the unsuccessful one doesn't.

gcc12.2 with -std=c++20 flag

```
error: the value of ‘str1’ is not usable in a constant expression
      constexpr auto numArgs = count(FMT); \
```

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


template<size_t arrSize>
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Number of format characters: " << arrSize << "\n";
}

constexpr size_t countFormat(const char* format)
{
    if(format[0] == '\0')
       return 0;
    return (format[0] == '%' ? 1u : 0u) + countFormat(format + 1);
}

constexpr size_t count(const char* format)
{
    return std::is_constant_evaluated() ? countFormat( format ) : 0;
}

#define LOGMSG(FMT) {  \
    constexpr auto numArgs = count(FMT); \
    print<numArgs>(); \
}

int main()
{
    const auto str1 = "Test %d %s";
    constexpr auto str2 = "Test %d %s";
    LOGMSG(str1);
    LOGMSG(str2);
    LOGMSG("Test %d %s");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `static const auto str1 = ...`.  Then, `str1` should be known at compile time (in your code, it isn't, because it's a stack-based variable).

Comment: Thanks Paul, but that doesn't work either.  My goal is to make the function work even if the parameter is not known at compile time. That's why I have the is_constant_evaluated in my count function.

Comment: In `LOGMSG(str1);`, are you expecting `std::is_constant_evaluated()` to be `true` or `false`? If `true`, then it's a problem that `str1` isn't `constexpr`. If `false`, how can you possibly expect to save the results into a `constexpr` variable?

Comment: @NathanPierson - I expect it to be false and return 0.  Doesn't the compiler know I am returning 0 to the constexpr variable ?

Comment: Even though the direct error that's being asked about is addressed by using `if constexpr`, there are other issues with the shown code that remain, after this fix.

Comment: This all seems a bit tricksy, is it really worth it?  Are you running on a platform with severe resource constraints or something?

Comment: @PaulSanders - I am trying to fix an existing codebase by not touching too many parts. I wrote some code so I could post it here and learn.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I will try if constexpr.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_constant_evaluated` is not a (magic) escape hatch when constant evaluation fails; generally it just **tells** you about the context in which you were called, with no ability to influence that context.  (There is an exception for `const` variables that can be “promoted” to `constexpr` for C++03 compatibility, but that exception doesn’t do what you want and it does hurt everyone’s head, so let’s not.)  It is possible to **SFINAE** on whether something is a constant expression, but only based on inputs that definitely are.

In general, constexpr programming doesn’t make C++ into an **interpreted** language; it’s a feature that it usually produces the same result as runtime evaluation, and the cases where it doesn’t are quite limited.

Moreover, constant evaluation has already failed in trying to **call** `count`, since it involves reading a (pointer) variable that isn’t available.  (It might be possible to work around this issue by using references, but that doesn’t address the fundamental impossibility here.)

Comment: but if the pointer is not available, shouldn't the compiler know that 0 can be still evaluated at compile time in the following `return std::is_constant_evaluated() ? countFormat( format ) : 0;`   That's the part I am having a hard time to follow.

Comment: Certainly when the call isn’t occurring during constant evaluation, the 0 is the only thing used.  What is the compiler supposed to do with it otherwise?

Comment: I expect the following to compile even if format is a pointer( and can't be constant evaluated).  
`constexpr auto numArgs = std::is_constant_evaluated() ? countFormat( format ) : 0`
Here either format can be constant evaluated and so passed to the function countFormat or the compiler ignores format and returns 0.  Instead the compiler complains.  That's the part I can't follow

Comment: @bramasub: How would `std::is_constant_evaluated` ever return `false` there?  It’s a `constexpr` initializer!

Comment: Thanks Davis.  I am beginning to see where I am going wrong here.  Basically I want an expression to ignore format if it is not eligible for constant evaluation and return 0 instead.  I will have to write SFINAE as you had recommended and see where that takes me

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to make the function work even if the parameter is not known at compile time.

If `constexpr` function is evaluated in constant expression doesn't depend of its parameter (known or not at compile time) but from the context where the function is called.

in your case:

```
constexpr auto numArgs = count(FMT);
```

`count` has to be evaluated as constant expression (so `std::is_constant_evaluated()` would be `true`).

When `FMT` is not known at compile time, then you will have error.

Your `count` implementation just "break" the runtime computation and doesn't allow the function to become `constexpr` when argument is not known at compile time.

You cannot branch depending of that argument "property".

Maybe you want overload on type constructed with `consteval`:

```
struct string_literal
{
    consteval string_literal(const char* s) : s(s) {}

    const char* s;
};

consteval size_t countFormat(string_literal format)
{
    if(format.s[0] == '\0')
       return 0;
    return (format.s[0] == '%' ? 1u : 0u) + countFormat(format.s + 1);
}

consteval size_t count(string_literal format)
{
    return countFormat(format);
}

constexpr size_t count(const char*const&)
{
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/79WanEb3W).